# Can we increase max_stack_depth for our Postgres database on Cloud SQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I can't find it in [Supported Flags](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#list-flags-postgres).
Are there no way to increase it?

Comment: Besides, I have never seen any reason to change that parameter. What is your reason?

Comment: Are you actually getting an error to that effect? If so it typically indicates a **major design/coding flaw**. An example would be a recursive routine with no terminating condition or a trigger function that issues a DML that caused to be called in the first place. There is NO work around you must fix the error, extending the max depth only more processing until it throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks all.
The reason to want to change the parameter was to solve a "stack depth limit exceeded" error.
I have not yet found out a query cause that error.
I will do that first.